# Need panel plots by each state, comprising three columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to draw a panel plot by each importing the attached csv data from given link (sample panel plot attached as well). Each state should contain three columns-  wt, avg, and observed, may be represented as legend or x-axis, and y-axis should show values.
I tried doing it in ggplot in R but couldn't succeed.
Please help plotting this panel plot.

Thanks,
Ranjeet

[csv file and sample panel plot](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1dNmGTI8_c9PK1QqmfIjnpbyzuiCXgxFC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pivot your data into a long format

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             State = c("Andhra Pradesh","Assam",
                       "Chhattisgarh","Goa","Gujarat","Haryana",
                       "Himachal Pradesh","Jharkhand","Karnataka","Kerala","Madhya Pradesh",
                       "Maharashtra","Manipur","Meghalaya","Odisha",
                       "Rajasthan","Tamil Nadu","Telangana","Tripura",
                       "Uttar Pradesh","Uttarakhand"),
                Wt = c(0.092066576,0.023850206,
                       0.209830138,0.021634993,0.104840239,0.047869204,
                       0.014229008,0.074248143,0.188853639,0.146991971,0.148019121,
                       0.189564031,0.085808664,0.011884387,0.094447032,
                       0.144303211,0.117343681,0.202923922,0.03803334,0.053658285,
                       0.119787823),
           Average = c(0.169362016,0.034176857,
                       0.186025075,0.016147401,0.130255382,0.062373442,
                       0.010081942,0.046698501,0.226191488,0.111300912,0.159568882,
                       0.183921131,0.137737491,0.00330759,0.07948901,
                       0.128878331,0.126884204,0.202655408,0.020871119,0.079228524,
                       0.11927443),
          Observed = c(0.083424473,NA,0.143548462,
                       0.010416667,0.006917477,0.061286714,0.077690577,NA,
                       0.1236367,0.279077323,0.181443002,0.222805733,
                       0.065743945,0.077922078,0.093420292,0.140944809,0.113274769,
                       NA,0.021522733,0.065261781,0.106522255)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(Wt:Observed)

ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(label = round(df$value, 2), 
            vjust = -0.8) +
  facet_wrap(~State)
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you very much Susan!!! I was also reaching to the same page, but when I convert this values to percentage and use the code it shows error - "Error in round(value, 2) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
>

Comment: Also was curious can I directly import and plot without writing all values in my script? Because copying and pasting large data would be tedious task and also need to use comma.

Comment: @RJ34 I would need to see your conversion to percentage, but the error seems to be telling you that your data are in character format, so you would need to round prior to converting.

Comment: Done. Thank you! Yeah. I was doing the same mistake.